# Update label on button hit, before calling function

Tags: java, swing, scala

I designed a GUI in Scala Swing, where I have a button that should:

1. update a label
2. call a function

In this exact order. Now I know, that for updating a label multiple times during the function call, I need to work with threads/actors. But is there an easier way, if I just want to do ONE update (change the label text to "processing") BEFORE doing the computation?

BTW, I know how to use threads, so I don't need any help if there is no easier way. A simple "no" would be enough in that case. But if there is, I would be glad for some help!

Comment: *"Thanks in advance,
cheers,
user1428162 :)"*

That is 3 lines of noise.  Leave it out in future.  If your name is that important to you, edit it into [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1428162/user1428162).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the "call a function" in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`